# Can we show that borel sigma field on $\mathbb R$ can be generated by $C = \{(-\infty, x], x \in \mathbb R\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I can show that:
$$
\begin{aligned} \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) &=\sigma((a, b),-\infty \leq a \leq b \leq \infty) \\ &=\sigma([a, b),-\infty<a \leq b \leq \infty) \\ &=\sigma([a, b],-\infty<a \leq b<\infty) \\ &=\sigma((a, b], -\infty \leq a \leq b < \infty) \\ &=\sigma(\text { open subsets of } \mathbb{R}) \end{aligned}
$$
Can we show that borel sigma field on $\mathbb R$ can be generated by  $C = \{(-\infty, x], x \in \mathbb R\}$? It's obvious that $\sigma((-\infty,x]) \subset \sigma((a,b])$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... and $(a,b]=(-\infty, b]\setminus(-\infty,a]$, so the other inclusion is obvious too.